# Create another column in the data frame based on the condition in one column and values in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, calculated-columns

I am trying to create another column in the data frame based on the condition in one column and values in another column.
My data frame looks like:

```
ID<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

Stock_ret <- c(-0.4, 0.5, 0.6,NA, NA, -0.8, -00.1, NA,-0.15, .28)

Covid.cases <- c(20, 200, 34, 10, 43, 15,11,3,4,55)

df1<-data.frame(ID, Stock_ret, Covid.cases)
```

The new column should take the values from covid.case column and add the current and last two values in case two consecutive NA are found in Stock_ret column. The new column should look like:

```
c.covid.case.trading<-c(20,200,34,10,43,68,11,3,7,55)

df2<-data.frame(ID, Stock_ret, Covid.cases, c.covid.case.trading)
```

I have searched the forum for the similar answers but my hardluck, the current solutions are not fitting in this scenario. Kindly help.

Comment: Why row 9 is 7, there is only one NA?

Comment: Becasue of the NA at row 8, It takes the current value of the covid case and the previous value. So at row 9, c.covid.case.trading=3+4=7

Comment: you mention "in case two consecutive NA are found"

Comment: I am very grateful for the help. What if the number of NA is not known before hand. It can be one, two or even three. How we can generalize this code then.

Answer (score 3):

With `lag` + `ifelse`:

```r
df1 %>% 
  mutate(new_col = ifelse(is.na(lag(Stock_ret, default = 0)) & is.na(lag(Stock_ret, n = 2)),
                          Covid.cases + lag(Covid.cases) + lag(Covid.cases, n = 2), Covid.cases))

#    ID Stock_ret Covid.cases new_col
# 1   1     -0.40          20      20
# 2   2      0.50         200     200
# 3   3      0.60          34      34
# 4   4        NA          10      10
# 5   5        NA          43      43
# 6   6     -0.80          15      68
# 7   7     -0.10          11      11
# 8   8        NA           3       3
# 9   9     -0.15           4       4
# 10 10      0.28          55      55
```

Comment: I am very grateful for the help. What if the number of NA is not known before hand. It can be one, two or even three. How we can generalize this code then.